# Как написать часть кода, который будет отсеивать другие слова и будет отвечать на них 'Я не Вас не понимаю'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Я решил научиться делать ботов для телеграма, но у меня появилась проблема. Мне нужно отсеять другие слова, кроме 'привет, помощь, помоги' в начале.
И можете, пожалуйста посоветовать фреймворки для pythona в котором будет больше возможностей для написания таких ботов

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(content_types =['text'])

def message_text(message):
    
if message.text.lower() == 'привет':       
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Привет, я бот')   
elif message.text.lower() == 'помощь':        
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'напиши помоги')    
elif message.text.lower() == 'помоги':     
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Администратор - ')
   

    Вот тут должен быть код , который будет отсеивать другие слова/буквы/цифры и т.д.

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я понял правильно ваш вопрос то просто в проверке добавьте блок `else`
И там что вы хотите пишите. А фреймворке для написание ботов посоветую aiogram
но сначала советую выучить telebot

Answer (score 0):

Для начала - TelegramBot.

По принципу работы, самый простой бот, это"Эхо бот". Чуть сложнее, это бот, который отвечает на те вопросы, которые вы сами пропишите внутри вашего кода.

'привет, помощь, помоги' - Эти слова будут командой на оживление вашего бота,и он даст прописанный вами ответ.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.infinity_polling()
```